# Can EF navigation properties be perceived as scalar properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF in winforms with two related tables: Job_Number(Master) & Rating_Value. Both tables contain a "JobID" column from which there is a 1 to many relationship. Two questions:

1. Should the properties from the data source have infinite cascading navigation properties referencing the other table? (I have a picture but my reputation disallows me to post it.) Mine does. Does it make a difference?
2. Next, after I drag the 1st table onto the form as details, when I drag the nested navigation property (representing the Rating_Value table) onto the form. If I use a grid, I get two columns that don't exist in the table. A "Count" and "IsReadOnly" columns. If I drag them on as details, I get an error: DatamMember property 'Job_Number' cannot be found on the DataSource. The second table doesn't have a "Job_Number" column. Why would it pull in a navigation property? At runtime, the "Rating_Value" table appears correct(the two afore mentioned columns are gone), but no data gets populated. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you comment with the picture URL?

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming 1 `JobNumber` has many `RatingValues`. There will be a navigation property on the  `JobNumber` entity to a collection of `RatingValues`. `RatingValues` will have a navigation property to a single `JobNumber`.
2. In a grid, include only the columns that interest you. If you want, for example, rows of `JobNumber`s along with each `JobNumber'`s `RatingValues` join the two tables.